# How to pad integers with leading zeroes in Netezza SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

Is it possible for me to change the  data input format in Netezza. For example, whenever I import the numbers like 007 or 041 or 063 the output is given as 7 ,41,63 respectively which screws up the business requirement.

Sorry for asking such a silly question as I am new in Netezza.

Comment: I assume if your data type was varchar instead of numeric it would preserve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer:

select lpad(s.Col_name,3,0) as result
from table name

Comment: Nick.McDermaid's comment on the question is more correct than this answer. If there is value to `007` beyond just `7`, then the data should be imported as a character field.

Comment: @JeremyFortune Not true. He isn't asking "which data type should I use to store numbers that require leading 0's." He was specifically asking how to "pad" integers with leading zeroes. "They would already have leading zeroes if they're stored as varchar" doesn't tell someone how to use LPAD(). He make work with data that he doesn't own and can only query.

Comment: We're just going to disagree on this one. In my view, if the business requirements imply that "007" means something and 7 doesn't, importing "007" into the database as an integer means you stripped the value of its meaning. What happens when "0007" means something different than "007"? How do you know how much to pad on output?

Comment: @JeremyFortune, You and I are playing for the same team here. I guess my comment spoke directly to the title of this question: "How to pad integers with leading zeroes in Netezza SQL". You can't answer that by saying "don't use integers." With that said, what you're saying is 100% correct, this clearly should be a varchar in the database.